# Is there a way to tell what changes are in a central CVS repo comparing to my local working copy?

Tags: version-control, cvs

I need a way to figure out what files were added/removed/modified in the CVS repository comparing to my local working copy, i.e. what will happen to my local copy if I run "cvs update". It is safe to assume that I don't have any uncommitted changes in my local copy.

The output of "cvs update" marks added and modified files as:

```
U filename
```

which helps, but it doesn't tell what files are deleted.

Is there an easy way to get all changed files and how they are changed? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i deleted the file b from another checkout of the project.

```
$ cvs status | grep Status
cvs status: Examining .
cvs status: `b' is no longer in the repository
File: a                 Status: Up-to-date
File: b                 Status: Entry Invalid
File: c                 Status: Up-to-date
```

you can see that file b is missing from the repository.

updating:

```
$ cvs up
cvs update: Updating .
cvs update: `b' is no longer in the repository
```

afterwards the file b was also gone in this checkout and the message about file b is never displayed again.

Comment: Thanks, lesmana. This is exactly what I need. I missed this kind of messages because they are in STDERR instead of STDOUT. I just need to test if it is reliable, i.e. always appearing for delete files.

Answer (score 0):

I remember I used

```
cvs update -nq
```

to get a quick overview of the status of my project.

cvs history is also a good source of information about what happened.

For details of changes there is cvs diff, but this is very verbose.